# how to write function in relationship using eloquent / etc with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
$data = Program::with('peserta', function ($query) {
                return $query->peserta()->whereBetween('tanggal', array($request->from, $request->until));
            })->get();
```

this code return error :

> mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given",
> exception: "ErrorException".

Help. thanks

Comment: try  $data = Program::with('peserta', function ($query)use($request) {
        return $query->whereBetween('tanggal', array($request->from, $request->until));
    })->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure function inside `with()` must be array and remove that `return`. [Example in laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models-on-morph-to-relationships)

```
$data = Program::with(['peserta' => function ($query) use($request) {
                $query->whereBetween('tanggal', array($request->from, $request->until));
            }])->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation sir. i forgot to check the doc

Comment: @FebriTahta You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

you should using whereHas to set condition for relationship:

```
$data = Program::whereHas('peserta', function ($query)use($request) {
     return $query->whereBetween('tanggal', array($request->from, $request->until));
 })->get()
```

and if you need have relationship data should be add 'with' to the query:

```
$data = Program::whereHas('peserta', function ($query)use($request) {
     return $query->whereBetween('tanggal', array($request->from, $request->until))->with('peserta');
  })->get()
```

Comment: thanks sir. im try to use this code and its also work